# Call not recording/transcribing

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

My server is returning the following twiml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Response><Dial callerId="+16122610242"><Number>+16128687242</Number></Dial>
  <Record recordingStatusCallback="https://myserver.com/twilio/recording" transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="https://myserver.com/twilio/transcribe" trim="trim-silence"/>
  </Response>
```

Why is the call not being recorded and transcribed?

Comment: Just a side note, what I want to do is get a recording and a transcription, seems like that is not possible by putting the record in the dial.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the record needed to be set on the Dial in order for it to record